# PHP/SQL - how to generate pages based on database rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php, mostly learning from examples, and having a little bit of trouble.
I already searched for this, but couldnt find exactly what i was searching for, or at least couldnt understand it.

I am trying to create somekind of a "news" system. I have a database with 3 columns:

1. tid - auto-incremented, the id # for the news i post
2. created_by - who created it...obviously
3. text - the news themselves

So, is there a way that every time i post some new article it gets a new unique page, based on its id?
In example - mysite.com/news.php?id=3  will show the article with "tid"=3 (from the sql table).

Lets say news.php is my main file and i want its content to change everytime when the ?id in the url changes.

Thanks and wish you a successful week ahead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please kindly check [ask]

Comment: There is a way. Check first the value of `tid` using [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), then pull out data based from the value

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$currentID = $_GET['current_id']; // get current id out of the link
// add some logic to validate it is a valid id to prevent sql injection
```

build the query which is get next post that is above 
current id and limit it to 1 post only

```
"SELECT * FROM news where id > $currentID limit 1";
```

back link would turn the `greater than` to a `less than`. you would need to have  checks to ensure you cant go below 0 and cant go max id number. A quick count of records would do it. or catch not found records to go back to the start